# Path.GetTempFileName causes Access to path '' is denied.in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, security

I am have a problem with  Path.GetTempFileName with running a Silverlight application. If I install my application to run Out-Of-browser it runs ok. It only fails when I run it locally i.e. In-Browser.

The error is 
File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied.

I cannot debug my application because of this issue. Can anyone suggest a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably no access to where ever Path.GetTempPath is pointing to.

If you have access to say My Documents, you could combine that with Path.GetRandomFileName, or if it's not happening too often, a simple time stamp.

Maybe you could use isolated storage. You could ask to make it a trusted application which would gain you access to the file system but doesn't work in say windows phone.

Comment: Isolated storage would work. The problem is I want to pass this path elsewhere in my program. Isolated storage will not give you the full path. I would have to rewrite a bunch of code. The program is working in out-of-browser so I don't want to make major changes.

Comment: You can't use say MyDocuments as the path, and GetRandomFileName then?

Comment: Hmmm, so no access to File system at all in browser?

Comment: Right. I'll mark this as the answer because I think isolated storage will work. I just don't have time to pursue it fully at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetTempFileName` method tries to access the temporary folder which is typically on the `C:\` (or whichever letter the main drive has been assigned). For security reasons, in-browser applications aren't allowed local access and that's likely why you're getting an error.